# Is there a way to count and calculate percentages

Tags: sql, group-by, count

In this image,

- I would like to count the occurrence of **header5** for each **header1** group.
- Plus I want to know the percentage of each occurrence in **header5**
  for each of the elements in header1

[image: image:]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Providing your data as linked image is good way to reduce number of answers. Write your example as well as your example code what you've done this far to your question.

Comment: I agree with ex4. We could also use a sample of the output that you are expecting. 
That said, for the first part it looks like a simple group by and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with cte_count as(
  SELECT header1 , count(header1) as total
  FROM tb_name
  group by header1
  ),

cte_sum as (

    SELECT header1, header5,count(header5) as ct
    FROM tb_name 
    group by header1, header5 
)

Select cte_sum.*, (cte_sum.ct*1.0*100 / cte_count.total) as percentage
From cte_sum left join cte_count
on cte_sum.header1 = cte_count.header1
```